# How are the Monogatari manga and light novels related?

Tags: monogatari-series

Back on the 10<sup>th</sup> of January 2018 [it was announced on Twitter](https://twitter.com/NISIOISIN_info/status/950895851974541314) that Bakemonogatari would be getting a manga.

> 【解禁】
>
> 『化物語』　漫　画　化　決　定
>
> 3月14日(水)発売「週刊少年マガジン」2018年15号ヨリ

Where [the first Japanese volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/978-4-06-511617-3) was released on [the 15<sup>th</sup> of June 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogatari_(series)#Manga), and has garnered 7 volumes in Japanese. [The first English volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/978-1-947194-97-7) was released on the 1<sup>st</sup> of October 2019.

---

How do these relate to the light novels and the animes?

Do they have the same stories (e.g. Bakemonogatari) and sub stories (e.g. Hitagai Crab)?
If they do, which stories and sub stories have been released?

Comment: Having not read it I'll refrain from posting an answer, but if you're still wondering after three years what I've heard is the manga more or less adapts the first two arcs before going completely off the rails and becoming its own thing--almost a tribute to the original instead.

Comment: @蛞蝓真宵 Thanks! I may buy the manga to validate if that's the case.